# Can i make views that cannot be hacked

Tags: html, asp.net-mvc, razor

I want to give a user a web application to deploy on their own server.  I want to put on an image (advertising) that the user must not be able to hack and remove.

Comment: They will always be able to remove the image. Your best hope is to make it hard enough that they won't do it.

Comment: If it's on their server, they can do whatever they want to it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you give the raw source code (PHP or ASP.NET), they can circumvent your code and remove your logo and etc. You will have to embed your image as a resource (In ASP.NET), and then dynamically load that image to the page using code (C#/VB.NET), and then compile the application, and distribute the binaries.

This way a casual user wont be able to remove. But an experienced user can still decompile your code or view your resource files, and change it.

Answer (score -1):

If you are asking

> Can I create ads that ad-blockers won't block?

The answer is: **no**

If you are asking

> Can I force my web application to display an ad from the customers server?

The answer is: Maybe. But it still could be blocked/filtered between their server and delivering it to the client. So, yes, you technically could ensure the ad is served from your application, but that's no guarantee the site visitor will ever see it.

It may make more sense to make it a legal (contractual) requirement, though. It would be a lot less complicated.

Comment: I think it's quite clear what the OP is asking: whether it's possible to create a view that is always included and isn't removable

Comment: I was hoping my answer was clear enough in that even if it is possible, there's no guarantee it will be delivered. So it may be a futile endeavor from a technical implementation standpoint. Best to make it a legal requirement.